# How to calculate the exponential ratio between a few numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, ratio

If I go onto Wolfram alpha and type `2 **x == 56` I see that x is around 5.8. What is a formula I can use to find the exact number (given use of a calculator)?

For example I have the following two times which are runtimes of a computation:

```
a = 0.005689493999852857
b = 151.89659522200054
```

I want to find the value of `x` such that `a^x = b`

So tried `log a (b)` which gave me `-0.9717681977154843`

My hunch is that since `a` is less than one, it needs to be given a negative exponent. However I'm not sure how to use this negative value, as opposed to a positive one. Should I just add one to both `a` and `b` before doing the logarithm, to ensure it's a positive exponent?

Comment: Have you studied logarithms?

Comment: You need to use a logarithm, but exact numbers are going to be hard to come by.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have. I was up to multivariable calculus in college before I stopped. I just haven't done it for a little while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking logarithms of both sides will convert this to a linear equation which is easily solved:
$$2^x=56$$
$$\log(2^x)= \log 56 \tag{take $\log$ of both sides}$$
$$x\log 2 = \log 56\tag{property of logarithms}$$
$$x=\frac{\log 56}{\log 2}\tag{solve linear equation}$$

This works for any base of the logarithm. Calculators typically have $\log_{10}$ or $\log_e$ (often denoted "LOG" and "LN", respectively). Using the latter, I get the approximation

$$x \approx \frac{4.02434}{0.69315}\approx \boxed{5.80735}$$

The property of logarithms we used in the third line was $\log a^b=b\log a$.

Comment: if the base for some inputs is less than one, then those results will be negative exponents. Is there a way I could compare these with other inputs that produce a positive exponent?

Comment: @maxpleaner I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but perhaps you might be interested to note that $\ln \frac{1}{a}=\ln a^{-1}=-\ln a$, so if $\ln a$ was negative, $\ln \frac{1}{a}$ would be positive instead.  That is, instead of asking what exponent $x$ is needed to make $0.5^x=16$, you can instead look at what exponent $x$ is needed to make $(\frac{1}{0.5})^x=16$ and then multiply by negative one to make it the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If 
$$
2^x = 56
$$
then
$$
x = \log_2 (56).
$$

Your calculator probably has a $\log$ key, but that will give you the base $10$ logarithm.

You can look up the formula for changing the base of a logarithm. (Search for
[log change base](https://www.google.com/search?q=log%20change%20base&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) does the job.)